# Extrude face along normal, following connected edge (extend geometry)?

Tags: geometry, extrude

I want to extrude a face in Blender along its normal, but I also want the vertices to follow their connected (but not selected during the extrusion) edges.  This means that the vertices would move relative to one another (in planes other than their extrusion direction), and extend the original geometry by extrapolation.  Another way to look at it would be to "slide" the vertices along their extrapolated, connected, and deselected edges.

This is difficult to describe in words, so let me provide an image.  Here's the face I'm extruding:

[image: object]

And here's how I'd like the vertices to move (viewed from above to make it clearer):

[image: vert direction]

Is it possible to do this in Blender?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38482/extrude-edge-along-roof-angle https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43123/extend-a-face-along-another-plane https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73386/extrude-while-sliding

Comment: Thanks, but none of these are what I want.  The first and last only apply to edges, not faces.  The second is in reference to the extrusion direction and does *not* allow vertices to move relative to one another, as I need.

Answer (score -1):

In face select, they will only extrude along their normals. In vertex select you can direct the extrusion where you want. And lets you do combinations like E-S-Y-Shift Z or whatever you need.

Comment: So this needs to be done a per-vertex level?  If so, it's not practical for me as the example I showed is a "watered down" version of what I need.  Some of the n-gons I want to extrude have hundreds of vertices.

Comment: If you select that face and then switch to vertex select, then you will have all the vertices you need in the selection.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this, I'm still not sure how this is supposed to work. The only method I've found is to select all the joining edges, subdivide them, then slide them with clipping disabled.  However, the surface this creates is horrible (as the edges/faces go past the vertex and then loop back), and you still have to select each connected edge instead of the face itself.